# who call the open() of a mouse driver?

Tags: c, linux, driver

When we had created a Linux character driver, we call open("/dev/xxxx") in user space to invoke the open() of that driver.

However, for example, a mouse device, there is no userspace application ( in my understanding now ) will open/operate the mouse driver. In this case, who will invoke the open() of mouse driver?

Comment: There has to be a userspace application, which reads in and processes the mouse movement. i.e. an X server or a console application utilizing the mouse

Comment: Run `sudo lsof /dev/input/event*` to see which processes have those devices open. Use `cat /sys/class/input/eventX/device/name` to see the hardware device name each event device corresponds to.

Comment: when  a loadable module (in this case a mouse driver) is installed, a table is updated in the OS that informs the OS of the major and minor device numbers for that module.  typically the entry points for `init()`, `schedule()` `read()` `write()` `close()` are visible via the major and minor device numbers.  using the major and minor device numbers, the OS calls the `init()` function to initialize the module.  From then on, the OS uses the major and minor device numbers to call the appropriate entry points as needed

Comment: it sounds X will directly 'open' every 'input' device, ex: mouse, keyboard and joystick?